# Reverse a singly linked list

Tags: python-3.x

Reverse a singly linked list.

Example:

```
Input: 1->2->3->4->5->NULL
Output: 5->4->3->2->1->NULL
```

Here's what I saw online:

```
class Solution:
def reverseList(self, head):
    def reverse(prev, cur):                
        if cur:
            reverse(cur, cur.next)
            cur.next = prev
        else:
            nonlocal head
            head = prev


    reverse(None, head)
    return head
```

But I didn't get the process how it works after the if cur.

For example the test case is [1,2,3,4,5].

1. input None, 1 into the reverse function
2. cur exist, run reverse function with 1, 2
   ...
3. cur exist, run reverse function with 4, 5
4. cur does not exist, (then what???)

BTW why does listNode even exist? It is not as easy as others like list array or dictionary. When should i use it?

Comment: Protip: If you find code that starts with `class Solution:`, disregard it and continue googling.

Answer (score 0):

There's no efficient way to do this. The only way without interacting with the list beforehand, is an algorithm of a complexity of `O(n * n)`, where you repeatedly go through the linked list, find last element and remove it, while adding it to a new linked list, until the first list is completely empty. If you wanted to preserve that list, you'd have to recreate that list during the reversing or simply copy it beforehand, not fun at all. This is what example you posted does.

```
def reverse(prev, cur):                
    if cur: # this should actually be if cur is not None:
        reverse(cur, cur.next) # call same method on next node
        cur.next = prev # when we are back from recursion hell, set previous one as next one, because we are reversing
    else: # we finally reached the end
        nonlocal head # excuse me, this is in a class but you wrap in multiple functions and use nonlocal??? Where did you even dig out this thing from?
        head = prev # head now becomes the previous node, because this node is None, or, end of the list
```

If you just want to learn about them, then this algorithm is perfectly fine, in any other case, you should at least upgrade to doubly linked list, you'll use insignificant amount of memory to speed up reversal a lot.

If you create your own doubly linked list, reversing could be as fast as swapping end and start "pointers", if you write it in a way where every node has two references, left and right in a list, such as `neighbours = [left, right]`, your linked list could store a value called advance direction, which would be either 0 or 1, meaning that you could reverse entire list from `start to end while going to left to right` to `end to start while going right to left` by merely swapping start with end and changing "advance value" from 1 to 0. The advance value would be wrapped in a method like `next()`, which would look something like this:

```
def next(self):
    if self.current is None:
        return None # could be return self.current or even just "return", this is Python
    self.current = self.current.neighbours[self.advance_value]
    return self.current
```

When advance_value is 0, it goes left, when advance_value is 1, it goes right through the list, all elements stay in their place, but to whoever is accessing it, it looks like it's reversed.